# How to solve error "invalid conversion of char to char*" when using strupr and strlwr?

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;
    char s[100];
    cin >> s;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
    {
        if(islower(s[i])==1)
        {
            s[i]=strupr(s[i]);
            cout << s[i];
        }
        else
        {
            s[i]=strlwr(s[i]);
            cout << s[i];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

These two lines i.e. `s[i]=strupr(s[i])` and `s[i]=strlwr(s[i])` shows this error :

> invalid conversion from char to char*.

How can I solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You should use these two instead:

```
s[i] = std::toupper(s[i]);
s[i] = std::tolower(s[i]);
```

Remember to include `<cctype>`. Here is a link to some documentation of [std::toupper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) and [std::tolower](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower).

The problem is that `strupr` and `strlwr` work on entire strings, not single characters. Moreover, they operate in-place and they are non standard.

*Side note:*

You could consider using a `std::string s` instead of `char s[100]`, this removes the current overflow opportunity in `cin >> s;`.

**Update:**

It is possible to use [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) like so:

```
std::transform(std::begin(s), std::end(s), std::begin(s), [] (char c) { return std::islower(c) ? std::toupper(c) : std::tolower(c); });
```

One benefit of using `std::begin(s)` and `std::end(s)` is that it works for both `std::string`, `std::vector` and even `char[100]`.

Comment: @bhartendupandya You should accept the answer that most precisely answered your question.

Answer (score 3):

`strupr` and `strlwr` expect a `char*` and not a `char` as their parameter.

You would need to pass the whole `s` array instead of `s[i]`

Alternatively use the [`std::toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) and [`std::tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) which would allow you to do each character in turn.

You can also get rid of the raw loop by using std::transform and a predicate or lamda

```
char InvertCase(char c)
{
    return islower(c) ? std::toupper(c) : std::tolower(c);
}

std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), back_inserter(result), InvertCase);
```

Answer (score 2):

`sdtrupr` and `strlwr` take [char * as an argument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235331.aspx). To convert a single character use [`tolower`](http://www.cprogramming.com/fod/tolower.html) and `toupper`

Answer (score 2):

`strupr()` modifies in place its string (that is, `char[]`) argument replacing all lowercase letters with uppercase. I think that you are confusing `strupr()` with `toupper()`.

Note that by using `strupr()` or `toupper()` you are making an implicit assumption that each `char` represents a character; this is not true for multi-byte encodings such as UTF-8.